# iterrate and save each stock historical data in dataframe without downloading in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I would like to pull historical data from yfinance for a specific list of stocks. I want to store earch stock in a separate dataframes (each stock with its own df).

I can download it to multiple csv's through below code, but I couldn't find a way to store them in different dataframes (wihtout having to download them to csv)

```
import yfinance
    stocks = ['TSLA','MSFT','NIO','AAPL','AMD','ADBE','ALGN','AMZN','AMGN','AEP','ADI','ANSS','AMAT','ASML','TEAM','ADSK']

    for i in stocks:

        df = yfinance.download(i, start='2015-01-01', end='2021-09-12')
        df.to_csv( i + '.csv')
```

I want my end results to be a dataframe called "TSLA" for tsla historical data and another one called "MSFT" for msft data...and so on

I tried:

```
stock = ['TSLA','MSFT','NIO','AAPL','AMD']

df_ = {}     
for i in stock:
    df = yfinance.download(i, start='2015-01-01', end='2021-09-12')
    df_["{}".format(i)] = df
```

And I have to call each dataframe by key to get it like `df_["TSLA"]` but this is not what I want. I need a datafram called only TSLA that have tsla data and so on. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by getting it without downloading it. If you want to save it locally, don't you need to download it? Please try this code. You can create a data frame for each from the list of stocks. `for i in stock:vars()[f'df_{i}'] = yfinance.download(i, start='2015-01-01', end='2021-09-12')`

Comment: If you want to keep every data in separated variable like`TSLA` then you only waste time - you can do it using `vars()`, `globals()` but it much better to keep it as dictionary because later you can use dictionary with `for`-loop to run the same code on all dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download data multiple times. You just have to split whole data with `groupby` and create variables dynamically with `locals()`:

```
stocks = ['TSLA', 'MSFT', 'NIO', 'AAPL', 'AMD', 'ADBE', 'ALGN', 'AMZN',
          'AMGN', 'AEP', 'ADI', 'ANSS', 'AMAT', 'ASML', 'TEAM', 'ADSK']

data = yfinance.download(stocks, start='2015-01-01', end='2021-09-12')

for stock, df in data.groupby(level=1, axis=1):
    locals()[stock] = df.droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
    df.to_csv(f'{stock}.csv')
```

Output:

```
>>> TSLA
             Adj Close       Close        High         Low        Open    Volume
Date
2014-12-31   44.481998   44.481998   45.136002   44.450001   44.618000  11487500
2015-01-02   43.862000   43.862000   44.650002   42.652000   44.574001  23822000
2015-01-05   42.018002   42.018002   43.299999   41.431999   42.910000  26842500
2015-01-06   42.256001   42.256001   42.840000   40.841999   42.012001  31309500
2015-01-07   42.189999   42.189999   42.956001   41.956001   42.669998  14842000
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...       ...
2021-09-03  733.570007  733.570007  734.000000  724.200012  732.250000  15246100
2021-09-07  752.919983  752.919983  760.200012  739.260010  740.000000  20039800
2021-09-08  753.869995  753.869995  764.450012  740.770020  761.580017  18793000
2021-09-09  754.859985  754.859985  762.099976  751.630005  753.409973  14077700
2021-09-10  736.270020  736.270020  762.609985  734.520020  759.599976  15114300

[1686 rows x 6 columns]
```

```
>>> ANSS
             Adj Close       Close        High         Low        Open  Volume
Date
2014-12-31   82.000000   82.000000   83.480003   81.910004   83.080002  304600
2015-01-02   81.639999   81.639999   82.629997   81.019997   82.089996  282600
2015-01-05   80.860001   80.860001   82.070000   80.779999   81.290001  321500
2015-01-06   79.260002   79.260002   81.139999   78.760002   81.000000  344300
2015-01-07   79.709999   79.709999   80.900002   78.959999   79.919998  233300
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...     ...
2021-09-03  368.380005  368.380005  371.570007  366.079987  366.079987  293000
2021-09-07  372.070007  372.070007  372.410004  364.950012  369.609985  249500
2021-09-08  372.529999  372.529999  375.820007  369.880005  371.079987  325800
2021-09-09  371.970001  371.970001  375.799988  371.320007  372.519989  194900
2021-09-10  373.609985  373.609985  377.260010  372.470001  374.540009  278800

[1686 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create global or local variable like

```
globals()["TSLA"] = "some value"

print(TSLA)
```

```
locals()["TSLA"] = "some value"

print(TSLA)
```

but frankly it is waste of time. It is much more useful to keep it as dictionary.

With dictionary you can use `for`-loop to run some code on all dataframes.
You can also seletect dataframes by name. etc.

Examples:

```
df_max = {}

for name, df in df_.items():
    df_max[name] = df.max()
```

```
name = input("What to display: ")

df_[name].plot()
```